# What does this message mean? from: can't read /var/mail/ex48 (Learn Python the Hard Way ex49)

Tags: python

In ex49, we are told to call the the lexicon.py file created in ex48 with the following command.

When I try to import the lexicon file with the following command

```
    >>> from ex48 import lexicon
```

it returns the following:

```
    from: can't read /var/mail/ex48
```

I've tried looking this up. What does this mean? Is a file in the wrong place?

Answer (score 24):

You need to add the shebang to the first line of your program.  Put in `#!/usr/bin/python` or where ever your python bin is located and your program will run.

Comment: it's not a script, he's running it at the prompt

Answer (score 11):

You didn't type "from ex48 import lexicon" in the Python shell, you typed it in at the command line.  "from" is the command to list who mail is from, hence the /var/mail location.

You can tell this from the different error messages the commands produce:

```
localhost-2:~ $ from ex48 import lexicon
from: can't read /var/mail/ex48
localhost-2:~ $ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ex48 import lexicon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ex48
```

Comment: So are you saying that I type it into the lexicon.py file? How do I run my lexicon game scanner (ex49)?

Answer (score 2):

## Enter in python Environment first

I am new to python and I guess this should be a rookie mistake.
I was running this line in my command line

```
from blogpost import db
```

And I got the same error

> can't read /var/mail/flaskblog

The problem was I did not enter in the Python environment and ran the python command.

**Solution?**
Enter in the python environment first

**How to enter in python environment?**
Type `python` or `python3`

```
python
from blogpost import db
```

[image]